# Wordpress: how to pass data from js to php where data is from php foreach anchor

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have this code/query:

```
$global_var = '';
        $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'product',
                'posts_per_page' => 50,
                'product_cat' => $global_var
        );
```

I wanted to manipulate it's $global_var to filter the products/data being displayed by category.
(trying to do ajax display of products filtered by list of anchored categories)

ref link: https://www.cosmina.co.th/product?lang=en

The source of filtering will be from this code:

```
foreach ( $parent_product_cats as $product_cat_obj ) {
        echo '<a id="cat_name">'.$product_cat_obj->name.'</a><br>';
}
```

I was able to create the list of this code and was able to test the anchor tag data thru this javascript.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#cat_name').click(function(){
        alert($(this).text());
    }); 
});
```

My struggle was:

1. The click event only works for the first index of the foreach,
2. After this, passing the anchor value to the $global_var of php.

Comment: If you want to pass a value to PHP using JavaScript, you are going to need AJAX or a form submission.

Comment: Hi @Kei, yes i get that but the thing is, the click event only works on the first loop of <a> tag. I get the text from the first loop but the second, no.

Comment: There are so many duplicates of this here on SO. Please try searching before posting a new question.  HTML IDs must be unique. You are using the same ID for every link.